# Laravel Query Builder - Ordering on a Custom Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I want to sort my Laravel query builder results on a custom column (concat of first_name and last_name).

What I have done is-

```
    $summary = DB::table('service_rating')
                ->join('partners', 'partners.id',   '=', 'service_rating.partner_id')
                ->join('users',     'users.id',     '=', 'partners.user_id')
                ->select(
                            DB::raw("CONCAT( users.first_name,' ', users.last_name) as lawn_pro"),
                            DB::raw ('AVG(service_rating.rating)                    as rating'),
                            DB::raw ('COUNT(service_rating.rating)                  as jobs'),
                            DB::raw ('SUM(service_rating.rating)                    as payout')
                        )
                ->where('customer_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->whereRaw('service_rating.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL '.$no_of_day_to_show.' DAY')
                ->groupBy('service_rating.partner_id')
                ->orderBy('lawn_pro', 'asc');
```

So, I am getting error for this line -

```
                ->orderBy('lawn_pro', 'asc');
```

And error is like this-

[image]

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: `->orderBy("CONCAT( users.first_name,' ', users.last_name)","asc")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are using the `count()` function on your query, this ignores the select attributes because we only want to know the count of the rows. Because of this, `lawn_pro` is not available in the query.

I would suggest to execute the query and then count the available rows.

```
$rows = $summary->get();
$count = count($rows);
```

Comment: If I need to count, I would not use orderby

Comment: Then why does your query start with `SELECT count(*) FROM ...`. Please show us all your whole code for this query so we can see what is happening.